# Navigation Drawer blocks other components

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to add Navigation Drawer to my android application.

I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android)

I successfully added the navigation drawer. 
The problem is when I add the component, the other buttons and components be inactive. Like three dot in action bar, it does not list the items. When I set visiblitiy of Drawer layout as gone, then three dot in action bar is working.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private String mActivityTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time for an upgrade!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();
    addDrawerItems();

    setupDrawer();
    toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_id);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}

private void setupDrawer() {

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Navigation!");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}


private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] osArray = { "Android", "iOS", "Windows", "OS X", "Linux" };
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

This is my content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.hale.myapplication.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
<include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navList"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.hale.myapplication.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
<include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navList"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is screenshot. The three dots is near the title
[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us your layout code

Comment: thanks I forgat, now added.

Comment: well, i won't bore you asking for one more thing, can you upload screenshot?

Comment: of course, in a minute

Answer (score 0):

first change you theme into something like this

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Toolbar</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="Toolbar" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light</item>
</style>
```

this is how i used my main content layout, where you see a drawerLayout and it has LinearLayout, inside this i have a frameLayout where i add content to show. you should use instead NavigationViewer instead of ListView as google suggests doing it.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!-- this is your ActionBar layout -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar   
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" 
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />


    <!-- Your content goes inside this layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>



<!-- you should use such NavigatinView instead of ListView -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation.view"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_profile"
    app:itemBackground="@xml/activated_navigation_menu_item"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>
```

Comment: Okay, I did it. But now how can I hide and show view with onclick? It is opened

Comment: which view are you talking about?

Comment: The navigationview

Comment: can you tell me more about it?